# Spring Boot, OAuth2 authentication is lost between requests

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

EDIT:

log from org.springframework.security:

```
2022-01-17 12:31:03.495 IST
2022-01-17 10:31:03.495 DEBUG [080-exec-5] o.s.s.w.s.SessionManagementFilter - Request requested invalid session id D5F8BA31A3D7466AK3K3C8EA26A4F037
Default

2022-01-17 12:31:03.495 IST
2022-01-17 10:31:03.495 DEBUG [080-exec-5] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter - Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
Debug

2022-01-17 12:31:03.495 IST
"Request requested invalid session id D5F8BA31A3D7466AK3K3C8EA26A4F037"
Debug

2022-01-17 12:31:03.495 IST
"Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext"
Default

2022-01-17 12:31:03.494 IST
2022-01-17 10:31:03.494 DEBUG [080-exec-5] o.s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter - Set SecurityContextHolder to empty SecurityContext
Debug

2022-01-17 12:31:03.494 IST
"Set SecurityContextHolder to empty SecurityContext"
Default

2022-01-17 12:31:03.493 IST
2022-01-17 10:31:03.493 DEBUG [080-exec-5] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Securing GET /logo192.png
Debug

2022-01-17 12:31:03.493 IST
"Securing GET /logo192.png"
```

*****But if I look in the logs some requests after I can get the valid auth:**

Debug
2022-01-17 12:31:03.945 IST
"Set SecurityContextHolder to SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=OAuth2AuthenticationToken [Principal=com.***.security.oauth.CustomOAuth2User@***, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=***, SessionId=9438C880A19C93AADJI206B9B8B3386], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_USER, SCOPE_https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email, SCOPE_https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile, SCOPE_openid]]]"
Debug

2022-01-17 12:31:03.945 IST
"Retrieved SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=OAuth2AuthenticationToken [Principal=com.***.security.oauth.CustomOAuth2User@***, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=***, SessionId=9438C880A19C93AADJI206B9B8B3386], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_USER, SCOPE_https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email, SCOPE_https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile, SCOPE_openid]]]"
Debug

2022-01-17 12:31:03.945 IST
"Retrieved SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=OAuth2AuthenticationToken [Principal=com.***.security.oauth.CustomOAuth2User@***, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=***, SessionId=9438C880A19C93AADJI206B9B8B3386], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_USER, SCOPE_https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email, SCOPE_https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile, SCOPE_openid]]]"
Default

2022-01-17 12:31:03.944 IST
2022-01-17 10:31:03.944 DEBUG [080-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Securing GET /auth/api/getBasicInfo

it looks like the session id is inconsistent

---

I use spring security builtin oauth2 social login option,
I implemented an OAuth2LoginSuccess class with the onAuthenticationSuccess method and inside of it I fetch the user the corresponds to the social id I got from the oauth:

```
CustomOAuth2User oAuth2User = (CustomOAuth2User) authentication.getPrincipal();
int sociald = oAuth2User.getAttribute("id");
User user = usersUtils.getUserBySocailId(socialId);
enter code here
// add the user details to the Auth
SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
((OAuth2AuthenticationToken) authentication).setDetails(user);
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
```

If I debug inside the onAuthenticationSuccess I can see a valid auth with all the user details.

after the login I redirect to the home page and i send a auth get request to the server to check if there is a user logged in.

the problem is that 50% of the times the request is completed successfuly and the user can make authenticated requets.

but the other 50% i get redirected automaticly to Login page and when i check the log is see that Spring boot says that the user is unauthenticated and the auth is lost.

But in the onAuthenticationSuccess i can always see the correct auth.

My ApplicationSecurityConfig looks like this:

```
    http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/login*", "/signin/**", "/signup/**", "/oauth2/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(Constants.ADMIN_PREFIX + "/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers(Constants.AUTH_PREFIX + "/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "USER")
            .antMatchers(Constants.PUBLIC_PREFIX + "/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().permitAll()
            .and()
            .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(new UnauthenticatedRequestHandler())
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .passwordParameter("password")
            .usernameParameter("email")
            .loginPage("/Login")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/loginSecure").permitAll().successHandler(new LoginSuccess()).failureHandler(new FailureSuccess())
            .and()
            .oauth2Login()
            .loginPage("/Login")
            .userInfoEndpoint()
            .userService(oAuth2UserService)
            .and()
            .successHandler(new OAuth2LoginSuccess())
            .and()
            .rememberMe()
            .rememberMeParameter("remember-me")
            .tokenValiditySeconds((int) TimeUnit.DAYS.toSeconds(21))
.userDetailsService(this.applicationUserService)
            .and()
            .logout()
         .clearAuthentication(true).invalidateHttpSession(true).logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
            .addLogoutHandler(new CustomLogOutHandler());
```

And this is the function i check if the user is logged in:

```
   @GetMapping(Constants.AUTH_PREFIX + "/checkUserLogged")
public Integer checkUserLogged(Authentication authentication,HttpServletRequest request) {
    try{
        if (authentication != null) {
            User (User) authentication.getDetails();
            if (user == null) {
                return -1;
            }
            return user.getId();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        logger.warning(e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
    return -1;
}
```

but when the problem occur it dosen't get to run the controller because spring security return unauthrozed error before.

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Can you add the logs?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're doing, but I'm eager to see the answers.

Comment: The log just says there is no Authenticated user

Comment: Spring Security holds the auth context in the users session, so perhaps there is something going wrong with that? Either way turn on debug logging for ` org.springframework.security` , that should give an idea for where it's going wrong

Comment: @stringy05 i changed the org.springframework.security to debug and got the following the the auth is lost:

2022-01-17 12:31:03.495 IST
"Request requested invalid session id D5F8BAJKL23JKL32LLEA26A4F037"

Debug
2022-01-17 12:31:03.495 IST

"Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext"
Default
2022-01-17 12:31:03.494 IST
2022-01-17 10:31:03.494 DEBUG [080-exec-5] 

o.s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter - Set SecurityContextHolder to empty SecurityContext
Debug

2022-01-17 12:31:03.494 IST
"Set SecurityContextHolder to empty SecurityContext"

Comment: i added the full log to the questions body, it seems like the sessions id is lost between the requests

Comment: Isn't it strange to keep session with oauth2? I prefer stateless services. If you want to keep JSessionId with oauth2, it can be problematic. State can be stored in JWT or database. You can read username from Json and load it to SecurityContextHolder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, I hope this could help.

The thing that caused the problem for me was that GCP and GAE use multiple instances of the server, and if the user is logged in a certain instance
does not mean the other instances are familiar with it too because the Spring HTTPSession is in-memory.

I Switched the Session platform to use the spring-session jdbc using the following configuration in the application.properties :

```
spring.session.store-type=jdbc
```

-- you can use redis instead of jdbc, as long as the session is stored in a shared place among all instances.

also added the transaction manager to the SecurtityConfig:

```
@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(DataSource dataSource) {
    return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource);
}
```

and added the following configurations :

```
    http.csrf().disable()
            .sessionManagement()
            .maximumSessions(1)
            .and()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.ALWAYS)
```

In addition like @stringy05 mentioned the authrizenClient Repository needs ti be updated too:

```
    /**
 * Use the servlet container session store for authorized OAuth2 Clients
 */
@Bean
public OAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository authorizedClientRepository() {
    return new HttpSessionOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository();
}
```

and add the .authorizedClientRepository line to the httpconfig:

```
....
                .oauth2Login()
            .loginPage("/Login")
            .authorizedClientRepository(authorizedClientRepository)
            .authorizationEndpoint().and()
            .userInfoEndpoint()
            .userService(oAuth2UserService)
            .and()
            .successHandler(new OAuth2LoginSuccess())
```

....

Regarding the GAE, I added the following line to the app.yaml file:

```
  network:
    session_affinity: true
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an answer, however too long for a comment..

It looks like the session is getting lost for some reason, definitely focus on that.

In a default Spring Boot config the session is managed by the underlying servlet container, so its worth checking that is functioning properly. Things to check:

- Are you running more than 1 app server node? If so, ensure the session is using some sort of cluster aware config (ie Redis / JDBC), local session will fail here for sure
- It's worth checking the defaults with OAuth2 login in Spring Boot. eg  you could try and specify the OAuth2 session using the `HttpSessionOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository` and a `SpringSessionBackedSessionRegistry`

Basically enable all the logs and try and observe the session states from the servlet container when the problem occurs.

Getting the oauth2 session working correctly can be non-trivial, especially given there are not many good blog / docs that describe what spring boot is doing.

That said, here's an example of a working Redis backed Spring Boot config with OAuth 2 login, which might be useful as a reference for you:

app config:

```yaml
spring:
  session:
    store-type: redis
    redis:
      namespace: sample:api
      flush-mode: immediate
  redis:
    host: localhost
    port: 6379
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
# add your oauth2 client details here
```

```java
public class SecurityConfig<S extends Session> extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository;

    @Autowired
    private RedisIndexedSessionRepository redisIndexedSessionRepository;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .sessionManagement()
                .maximumSessions(1)
                .sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry())
                .and()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.ALWAYS)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests(
                        a -> a.antMatchers("/api/login/callback").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated())
                .oauth2Login()
                .authorizationEndpoint()
                .authorizationRequestResolver(
                        new DefaultOauth2AuthorizationRequestResolver(
                                this.clientRegistrationRepository, OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter.DEFAULT_AUTHORIZATION_REQUEST_BASE_URI))
                .and()
                .defaultSuccessUrl("http://localhost:3000/users")
                .authorizedClientRepository(authorizedClientRepository());
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringSessionBackedSessionRegistry<?> sessionRegistry() {
        return new SpringSessionBackedSessionRegistry<>(this.redisIndexedSessionRepository);
    }

    /**
     * Use the servlet container session store for authorized OAuth2 Clients
     */
    @Bean
    public OAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository authorizedClientRepository() {
        return new HttpSessionOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository();
    }

    /**
     * specify CORS to work from SPA UI
     */
    @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOriginPatterns(List.of("http://localhost:3000*"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"));
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }

    @Configuration
    public static class HttpSessionEventPublisherConfig {

        /**
         * enables session expiry notification
         *
         * <p>Needs to be declared in a different class from the `SpringSessionBackedSessionRegistry` to
         * avoid a circular dependency
         */
        @Bean
        public HttpSessionEventPublisher httpSessionEventPublisher() {
            return new HttpSessionEventPublisher();
        }
    }
```